# Composer not using vcs version pointing to forked repo

Tags: composer-php

I have seen this same error in other questions, but solutions offered are not fixing the issue for me.

I created a fork (and PR to master, the only branch) of this repo:

https://github.com/ipalaus/geonames/blob/master/composer.json

my fork is here:

https://github.com/jrmadsen67/geonames/blob/master/composer.json

(the change is to update the Laravel version dependencies)

In my projects, I am using:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/jrmadsen67/geonames"
    }
],  
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "ipalaus/geonames": "0.2.*"
},
```

However, I still get the "Your requirements could not be resolved..."

```
"ipalaus/geonames v0.2.0 requires illuminate/database 4.1.* ->"
```

You can see it is looking for 4.1 laravel components, not 4.2 as my fork is telling it.

If there is other info you require, please let me know.

TIA!

Comment: Hm, the problem I am seeing is your branch is master, if it was different it could have been made like `"ipalaus/geonames": "dev-<branch>"` . But in this case I am not sure how `dev-master` is recognized by composer though. See http://harikt.com/blog/2014/05/29/hidden-gems-of-composer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest is from your current master branch checkout to a new branch. Normally bug-fix etc are assumed to be on different branch. As dev-master contains the bug fix checkout to different branch from master .

```
git checkout -b new-branch
git push origin new-branch
```

In `composer.json`

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/jrmadsen67/geonames"
    }
],  
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "ipalaus/geonames": "dev-new-branch"
},
```

Hope that help!

Comment: thanks Hari - think the issue may have been more a local machine thing, but this was most helpful. He accepted my PR to update the versioning, so whole thing is a bit mute now